# percentage, rate, or ratio which is correct?

Tags: nouns, mathematics

> My salary for last month was $1,000 and for this month was $1,100, that is, my salary increased by 10%.

In this case, which of the following is correct?

> The **rate/ratio/percentage** of change in my salary for this month with
>   respect to my salary for this month is an increase of 10%.

Comment: I'd say "percentage" since rate and ratio do not represent their value(s) with percent sign(%).

Comment: Any reasoning why you want to say it this way? *percentage* is correct, but it is redundant since you already wrote it in "10%". "My salary *increased by 10%* over last month" says the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

The % symbol means percent, so if you are using that, it is a percentage.

A rate is x per y like miles per hour

A ratio is x to y like the ratio of flour to milk in a recipe might be 1:1 if you put in equal amounts of both